# dplyr::summarize alphabetizes, but I need the original order

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)
```

I have a string of letters and letter-words:

```
myletters <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "AA", "BB", "BB")
```

I'd like to get a count of each letter, arranged in the original order.
All groups of similar letters and letter words will be grouped in the original string ... they will never be mixed. For example, this will never happen:

```
mylettersNever <- c("A", "B", "A", "C", "C", "C", "C", "AA", "BB", "BB")
```

I tried some things with `table()`, but it did the same as the following code.
This doesn't work:

```
myletters %>%
  tibble(letters = .) %>%
  group_by(letters) %>%
  summarise(n = n())
```

... because the output is

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  letters     n
  <chr>   <int>
1 A           2
2 AA          1
3 B           1
4 BB          2
5 C           4
```

... but I would like:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  letters     n
  <chr>   <int>
1 A           2
2 B           1
3 C           4
4 AA          1
5 BB          2
```

Help?

Comment: Convert your letters to a `factor` with the levels specified in the original order, and then `table` / `group_by` etc should respect that I think. E.g. `table(factor(myletters, levels=unique(myletters)))`

Comment: `forcats::as_factor` will convert to a factor and set the levels in the order in which they occur in the data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `count()` to do the counting according to some variable. Indeed, to keep the order, considering your character column as factor will help maintain levels in order

```r
library(tidyverse)
myletters <- c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "AA", "BB", "BB")

tibble(letters = myletters) %>%
  mutate(letters = as_factor(letters)) %>%
  count(letters)
#> # A tibble: 5 x 2
#>   letters     n
#>   <fct>   <int>
#> 1 A           2
#> 2 B           1
#> 3 C           4
#> 4 AA          1
#> 5 BB          2
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: You can directly do `tibble(letters = myletters) %>% count(letters = as_factor(letters))`.

Comment: I agree result is the same. I was decomposing the step. Thanks for the addition !

Comment: Your `tibble() %>% mutate(as_factor()) %>% count()` solution worked. Thank you, @cderv

Comment: this solution does not work when the column is numeric: try `data.frame(x=2:1 %x% rep(1,2), y=c(9,1,3,5)) %>% mutate(as_factor(as.character(x))) %>% group_by(x) %>% summarize(count=n())` 
(`as.factor` is the same and `as.character` is necessary because `as_factor` apparently doesn't accept numeric)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a hacky way but works. Basically assign an id column to each group based on whichever appears first and then drop id after summarizing. Also you can directly use `count` which groups and un-groups behind the scenes.

```
myletters %>%
  tibble(letters = .) %>%
  count(id = match(letters, unique(letters)), letters) %>%
  select(-id)

# A tibble: 5 x 2
  letters     n
  <chr>   <int>
1 A           2
2 B           1
3 C           4
4 AA          1
5 BB          2
```

Comment: I like it this because it avoids creating factors, thanks @Shree